# PHP get string with preg match

Tags: php, regex

I am sadly not so familar with regex - so someone can help me with this?
I have this string:

```
$theString = 'MYSTRING-[DDAADD]-IS_SO_BEAUTYFULL'
```

And all what I want is to extract the content between the 2 square brackets, in this example I should get 'DDAADD'.

> The target is to explode my string that I get 3 strings:

```
$first = 'MYSTRING-';
$second = 'DDAADD';
$third = '-IS_SO_BEAUTYFULL';
```

How do I reach it?

I try it with preg_match but I can't get it to work:

```
preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\[\]]+/', $string, $matches);
```

I also try this:

```
preg_match_all('/[A-Z\[\]]+/', $string, $matches);
```

Then I got my three strings, but without the '-'..

I try it whith preg_split but I don't reach my target properly:

```
preg_split("/\[([^\]]+)\]/", $myString);
```

Then I got only my 2 strings correct, but without the central part with DDAADD...

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you need to only get one `DDAADD` value? Or `preg_split('~[][]~', $s)` to get 3 values like `$first`, `$second`, and `$third`?

Comment: yes - I need the 3 strings.. thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_split` with `[][]+` regex to match one or more `[` or `]` symbols:

```
$s = "MYSTRING-[DDAADD]-IS_SO_BEAUTYFULL";
$arr = preg_split('~[][]+~', $s);
print_r($arr);
```

Output of the [sample demo](https://ideone.com/BWDAwd):

```
Array
(
    [0] => MYSTRING-
    [1] => DDAADD
    [2] => -IS_SO_BEAUTYFULL
)
```

Another approach is to use a `preg_match` with `\[([^][]+)]` regex (or `\[([A-Z]+)]`):

```
$s = "MYSTRING-[DDAADD]-IS_SO_BEAUTYFULL";
if (preg_match('~\[([A-Z]+)]~', $s, $res)) {
    echo($res[1] . "\n");
} // => DDAADD
if (preg_match('~\[([^][]+)]~', $s, $res)) {
    print_r($res[1]);
} // => DDAADD
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/MbEMKu)

Here, `\[` matches a `[`, `([A-Z]+)` captures into Group 1 one or more uppercase letters (or `[^][]+` matches 1 or more chars other than `[` and `]`) and `]` matches a literal `]`. The value is inside `$res[1]`.